# How to select SQL for column 1 not in column 2

Tags: sql

I have a table with four columns. The first column ID1 has one similar row in ID2. I like to select a query to get all rows from ID2, except the identical record. For instance:

```
ID1 Name1 ID2 Name2
-------------------
01  A     01  A
01  A     02  B
01  A     03  C
03  C     03  C
03  C     01  A
03  C     04  G
```

Select ID2, Name2 From table where ID2 <> ID1

Output should be:

```
ID2, Name2
----------
02   B
03   C
01   A
04   G
```

03/C and 01 A need to be here.
If I use distinct, then it exludes all identical records of ID1, which I don't want to. I am using classic ASP to select ID1 groups in SELECt option list. if I select 01, then SELECT option list for ID2 appear. I only want to see all ID2 that is not in ID1.

[image]

Can someone help me please?
Thanks.

Comment: Why are 03/C and 01/A in the result set?

Comment: Because 03/C and 01/A are another group of ID1. If I use distinct, then it exludes all identical records of ID1, which I don't want to. I am using classic ASP to select ID1 groups in SELECt option list. if I select 01, then SELECT option list for ID2 appear. I only want to see all ID2 that is not in ID1. Thanks.

Comment: @JennyTran If the below answer solver you question give it a green tick and possibly an upvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is no need for explanation:

```
select id2, name2
from t
where (id1 <> id2) OR (name1 <> name2)
```

Comment: As far as I understand given question, your answer is good enough for this current table content and specified output, but if `name1 != name2` and `id1 = id2` your query is going to print this record, and it shouldn't. There should be `AND` instead of `OR`

Comment: @ArielGrabijas *except the identical record* not the identical id.

Answer (score 1):

I think  you want `not exists`.  But your result set doesn't seem to match the description of the question.

```
select id2, name2
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id1 = t.id2 and t2.name1 = t.name2
                 );
```

Comment: it returned no records at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try 'distinct'

```
Select distinct ID2, Name2 From table where ID2 <> ID1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not entirely clear, assuming that `ID1` can't equal `ID2` AND `name1` can equal `name2` the proper answer would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID2, Name2 FROM tableName WHERE ID2 <> ID1
```

You select columns `ID2` and `Name2` but only those where `ID1` is not equal to `ID2`. There is also `DISTINCT`, it guarantees that only different values are returned.

if `name1` can't equal `name2` you have to use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID2, Name2 FROM tableName WHERE ID2 <> ID1 AND name1 <> name2
```

Comment: i added an explantion and picture at my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this will work:

```
select ID2,Name2 from tablename where ID1!=ID2 and Name1!=Name2
```